# is a record locked when entitymanger works on it?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a transaction which uses one entitymanager `em1`. Inside this transaction i call a method. Now this method creates one more entitymanager `em2`. Now `em2` operates on some data and return be one object. Now this object is populated with value of one row from db. Please note that `em2` is not closed. Somone else implemented this API and I am just using it.

Now if i try to delete the record returned by `em1` my code hangs and it then times out. Is it because em1 has locked that particular record?

pseudocode is as follows

```
start tx using em1
Obj a = newSomeobject().getdata(id);  //get data uses em2 and em2 is not closed.
// now  tx ties to update record returnd by getdata  and the code times out
```

Comment: @ DataNucleus: i caapend all the answerd of previvious questions.I was not aware that i should accept the answers.Am new to this site

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hibernate in an application managed EM then hibernate will automatically join it to the current transaction, see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html#d0e2782).

Comment: am usin open jpa as jpa provider

Answer (score 0):

In an optimistic transaction there should be no locking of such objects. Obviously inspecting the SQL sent to the RDBMS would reveal any "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" statements (or equivalent)